# Getting a list of the next n days of the week?

Tags: sql, string, parsing, google-bigquery

I have two columns of weekdays and the number of days between these weekdays like this:

```
Monday  | Saturday    | 13
Tuesday | Friday      | 54
Friday  | Wednesday   | 10
```

etc. I need to use SQL to make another column that contains a string with all the 13 or 54 weekdays between the two weekdays. So something like "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, ... Monday, Tuesday ... Friday, Saturday"

How can this be accomplished?
Thanks.

Comment: What SQL Server are you using? What client programming language?

Comment: I am using BigQuery, with standard SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT start, duration,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(
    REPEAT('Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,',CAST(duration/7+1 AS INT64)),
    CONCAT(r'', start, r'(?:(?:,\w+){', CAST(duration - 1 AS STRING), '})')
  ) days_list
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

you can test / play with it using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Monday' start, 'Saturday' finish, 13 duration UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tuesday', 'Friday', 54 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Friday', 'Wednesday', 10 
)
SELECT start, duration,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(
    REPEAT('Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,', CAST(duration / 7 + 1 AS INT64) ), 
    CONCAT(r'', start, r'(?:(?:,\w+){', CAST(duration - 1 AS STRING), '})')
  ) days_list
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```
Row start   duration    days_list    
1   Monday  13  Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday   
2   Tuesday 54  Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday    
3   Friday  10  Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday
```